# using csv instead of geodataframe: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, geometry, contains

I have a geodataframe, named gdf2, of the municipalities of the Netherlands, in which the attribute table looks like this:
[image]

Using the following code returns me whether a coordinate (point) lies within a certain municipality:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

point = Point(6.56667, 53.21917)

for i in range(len(gdf2['geometry'])):
  if gdf2['geometry'][i].contains(point) == True:
     print(gdf2['statnaam'][i])
```

This code returns me correctly 'Groningen', the municipality the point is in.

Now I want to do the same thing, but with a csv file of this.
A user inputs the latitude and longitude, named lat and lon here.
Here, lat and lon are type floats.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

gdf2.to_csv('gdf2.csv')

gdf_csv = pd.read_csv('gdf2.csv')

point = Point(lon, lat)

for i in range(len(gdf_csv['geometry'])):
    if gdf_csv['geometry'][i].contains(point) == True:
       print(gdf_csv['statnaam'][i])
```

When I run this, it gives me the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'.

What is going wrong here? I should be able to do the same in a csv file, right?

Comment: What if you try: `if point in gdf_csv['geometry'][i]`? Also, adding `== True` is redundant

Comment: @Maksim, thank you for replying. I already tried this. Sadly, this gives me another error: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Point'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by converting the csv basically back to GDF:

```
from shapely import wkt
gdf_csv.geometry = gdf_csv.geometry.apply(wkt.loads)
```

Now the following code works!

```
point = Point(lon, lat)

for i in range(len(gdf_csv['geometry'])):
    if gdf_csv['geometry'][i].contains(point) == True:
       print(gdf_csv['statnaam'][i])
```

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Just wanted to point out once again that the right side of the if condition (`== True`) is unnecessary. Your code will be more concise without it.

Comment: @Maksim you're correct indeed. Thank you!